# How to use Python command os.system() to feed input file besides just launching Orange program?

Tags: python, operating-system, system, orange

[image: My Orange program]

I would like to feed argument (ie: input file) to my Orange program. Does os.system() work? I only manage to launch my Orange program using that program (ie: os.system(abc.ows).
Is it possible to have sort of python command like "os.system(abc.ows, in=bgf.csv)?

Answer (score -1):

You can use `sys`.

```
import sys
print(sys.argv)
```

And if you run the script with some arguments it will print them.

Answer (score -1):

you must try

os.system("file_name > program")

i.e.
**os.system("bgf.csv > abc.ows")**

It means that you are redirecting bgf.csv file to abc.ows